# How to prove uniform convergence

Tags: functions, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I have the following sequence of functions before me:

$f_n(x)=0, \text{if}   x<\dfrac {1}{n+1}$

$=\sin(\dfrac {π}{x}),\text{if} \dfrac{1}{n+1}\leq{x} \leq{\dfrac{1}{n}}$

$=0,\text{if} x>\dfrac{1}{n}$.

I have to prove that this sequence of functions converges to a continuous function but not uniformly.

The sequence converges to $f(x)=0$ in a pointwise manner. To show that it does not converge uniformly, my idea to is to integrate this sequence of functions and if I am able to get a non-zero value of the integral then I am done.

The integral is :

$\int_\dfrac{1}{n+1}^\dfrac{1}{n} \sin\dfrac{π}{x} dx$

I performed a change of variable using $\dfrac{1}{x}=t$ which gives me the integral

$\int_{n}^{n+1}\sin{\dfrac{πt}{t^2}} dt$

How can I now show that this integral has a non-zero value? Or am I being completely off track in solving this problem? Please suggest.

Comment: Your approach may work, but is would be much easier to compute $\sup f_n(x)$ in order to disprove the uniform convergence.

Comment: Side note: Have a look at [`\begin{cases}…\end{cases}`](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5025/42969) for a nicer presentation of piecewise functions.

Comment: Try $t=\frac{1}{x}$ initially.  and $g_n(t)=f_n(x)$.  Your integral approach will work with $g_n$.

Comment: @herb steinberg This substitution is same as I tried.

Comment: By doing it first, the integral  will be$\int\limits_n^{n+1} sin(\pi t)dt=\pm\frac{2}{\pi}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach does not work. You have
$$
 \left | \int_{\Bbb R} f_n(x) \, dx \right| \le \int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n} 1 \, dx
= \frac{1}{n(n+1)}
$$
so that $\int_{\Bbb R} f_n(x) \, dx\to 0$ for $n \to \infty$.

That does not disprove the uniform convergence. As pointed out in the comments and in the other answer you can consider $\sup f_n(x)$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges pointwise to the null function, if it converged uniformly, it could only converge uniformly to the null function. Bu it doesn't, since$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\left|f_n\left(\frac1{n+1/2}\right)\right|=1.$$